# Let $F$ be a finite field. Determine all $x\in F$ s.t .: $x^2=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

What I've done so far:

This means that $x$ is auto-inverse with respect to multiplication.

I've seen that this holds for

- $x=1$, since $1\cdot 1=1$, and
- $x=(-1)$, since $(-1)(-1)=1$  (according to a theorem for rings)

It seems to be that $1$ and $(-1)$ are the only $x\in F$ that have this property. However, I can't prove why these two have to be the only ones.

Could you help me prove why this must be so. Or if not, what are other elements satisfying $x^2=1$ and why?

Comment: How many zeros can a polynomial of degree $d$ have in a field?

Comment: I see, thank you! At most two! Therefore these two are the only ones!

Comment: Note that the two are only different in chracteristics $\neq 2$.

Comment: I see, if we're in GF(2) then (-1)=1. Thank you!

Comment: Not only there, any field of characteristic $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x^2 = 1 \implies x^2 - 1 = 0 \implies (x-1)(x+1) = 0$.

Because $F$ is a field, $ab = 0 \implies a=0$ or $b=0$.

Comment: It's not so clear to me how this should answer the question. However, I accepted this answer in order to close the question. See the comments below the question for further explanations about the solution.

Comment: This shows that $x^2 -1 = 0$ if and only if $x - 1 = 0$ or $x+1 = 0$.

Comment: You should change all your implies to if only ifs imo.